# unresolved dependencies with "sbt clean compile"

Tags: scala, sbt

New to Scala here, I have this .sbt manifest file:

```
import sbt.Package._
import sbt._
import Docker.autoImport.exposedPorts

scalaVersion := "2.12.6"

enablePlugins(DockerPlugin)
exposedPorts := Seq(8666)

libraryDependencies ++= Vector (
  Library.vertx_lang_scala,
  Library.vertx_web,
  Library.scalaTest       % "test",
  // Uncomment for clustering
  // Library.vertx_hazelcast,

  //required to get rid of some warnings emitted by the scala-compile
  Library.vertx_codegen
)

packageOptions += ManifestAttributes(
  ("Main-Verticle", "scala:vertx.scala.myapp.HttpVerticle"))
```

I run this command:

```
sbt clean compile
```

and as with most JVM related tools I get about 1000 lines of output:

```
[info] Loading settings from plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from /home/oleg/codes/oresoftware/vertx-scala/project
[info] Updating {file:/home/oleg/codes/oresoftware/vertx-scala/project/}vertx-scala-build...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.5: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.5 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[warn]  1
[warn]  1
[warn]  1
[warn]  :: com.lucidchart#sbt-scalafmt;1.14: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.lucidchart#sbt-scalafmt;1.14 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[warn]  1
[warn]  1
[warn]  1
[warn]  :: org.scoverage#sbt-scoverage;1.5.1: Resolution failed several times for dependency: org.scoverage#sbt-scoverage;1.5.1 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[warn]  1
[warn]  1
[warn]  1
[warn]  :: net.virtual-void#sbt-dependency-graph;0.9.0: Resolution failed several times for dependency: net.virtual-void#sbt-dependency-graph;0.9.0 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[warn]  1
[warn]  1
[warn]  1
[warn]  :: se.marcuslonnberg#sbt-docker;1.5.0: Resolution failed several times for dependency: se.marcuslonnberg#sbt-docker;1.5.0 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[warn]  1
[warn]  1
[warn]  1
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]          com.eed3si9n:sbt-assembly:0.14.5 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]          org.scoverage:sbt-scoverage:1.5.1 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]          com.lucidchart:sbt-scalafmt:1.14 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]          se.marcuslonnberg:sbt-docker:1.5.0 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]          net.virtual-void:sbt-dependency-graph:0.9.0 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]          com.eed3si9n:sbt-assembly:0.14.5 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (/home/oleg/codes/oresoftware/vertx-scala/project/plugins.sbt#L1-2)
[warn]            +- default:vertx-scala-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]          org.scoverage:sbt-scoverage:1.5.1 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (/home/oleg/codes/oresoftware/vertx-scala/project/plugins.sbt#L3-4)
[warn]            +- default:vertx-scala-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]          com.lucidchart:sbt-scalafmt:1.14 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (/home/oleg/codes/oresoftware/vertx-scala/project/plugins.sbt#L2-3)
[warn]            +- default:vertx-scala-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]          se.marcuslonnberg:sbt-docker:1.5.0 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (/home/oleg/codes/oresoftware/vertx-scala/project/plugins.sbt#L5-6)
[warn]            +- default:vertx-scala-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]          net.virtual-void:sbt-dependency-graph:0.9.0 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (/home/oleg/codes/oresoftware/vertx-scala/project/plugins.sbt#L4-5)
[warn]            +- default:vertx-scala-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.5: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.5 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[error]         1
[error]         1
[error]         1
[error] 
[error] unresolved dependency: com.lucidchart#sbt-scalafmt;1.14: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.lucidchart#sbt-scalafmt;1.14 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[error]         1
[error]         1
[error]         1
[error] 
[error] unresolved dependency: org.scoverage#sbt-scoverage;1.5.1: Resolution failed several times for dependency: org.scoverage#sbt-scoverage;1.5.1 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[error]         1
[error]         1
[error]         1
[error] 
[error] unresolved dependency: net.virtual-void#sbt-dependency-graph;0.9.0: Resolution failed several times for dependency: net.virtual-void#sbt-dependency-graph;0.9.0 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[error]         1
[error]         1
[error]         1
[error] 
[error] unresolved dependency: se.marcuslonnberg#sbt-docker;1.5.0: Resolution failed several times for dependency: se.marcuslonnberg#sbt-docker;1.5.0 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[error]         1
[error]         1
[error]         1
[error] 
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.resolveAndRetrieve(IvyActions.scala:331)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$updateEither$1(IvyActions.scala:205)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.$anonfun$withModule$1(Ivy.scala:229)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.$anonfun$withIvy$1(Ivy.scala:190)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.sbt$internal$librarymanagement$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:70)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:95)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:80)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:99)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:60)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:50)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:185)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:182)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:228)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:190)
[error]         at sbt.librarymanagement.ivy.IvyDependencyResolution.update(IvyDependencyResolution.scala:20)
[error]         at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:56)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:38)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:91)
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:68)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$19(LibraryManagement.scala:104)
[error]         at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:224)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:104)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:87)
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChanged$1(Tracked.scala:149)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:118)
[error]         at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask$5(Defaults.scala:2353)
[error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
[error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:257)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:266)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:257)
[error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:167)
[error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:32)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
[error] (*:update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.5: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.5 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[error]         1
[error]         1
[error]         1
[error] 
[error] unresolved dependency: com.lucidchart#sbt-scalafmt;1.14: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.lucidchart#sbt-scalafmt;1.14 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[error]         1
[error]         1
[error]         1
[error] 
[error] unresolved dependency: org.scoverage#sbt-scoverage;1.5.1: Resolution failed several times for dependency: org.scoverage#sbt-scoverage;1.5.1 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[error]         1
[error]         1
[error]         1
[error] 
[error] unresolved dependency: net.virtual-void#sbt-dependency-graph;0.9.0: Resolution failed several times for dependency: net.virtual-void#sbt-dependency-graph;0.9.0 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[error]         1
[error]         1
[error]         1
[error] 
[error] unresolved dependency: se.marcuslonnberg#sbt-docker;1.5.0: Resolution failed several times for dependency: se.marcuslonnberg#sbt-docker;1.5.0 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[error]         1
[error]         1
```

does anyone know why my basic project skeleton which I created via:

**`sbt new vert-x3/vertx-scala.g8`**

does not compile?

**Update**, supposedly what I am missing are some plugins, here is `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n"      % "sbt-assembly"        % "0.14.5")
addSbtPlugin("com.lucidchart"    % "sbt-scalafmt"        % "1.14")
addSbtPlugin("org.scoverage"     % "sbt-scoverage"       % "1.5.1")
addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void"  % "sbt-dependency-graph"% "0.9.0")
addSbtPlugin("se.marcuslonnberg" % "sbt-docker"          % "1.5.0")
```

Comment: What SBT version do you have installed globally? I just created a project from scratch using that template and SBT 1.2.7 and everything compiled.

Comment: are you behind some kind of firewall that's restricting access to these dependencies?

Comment: @AlonsoDominguez I can't even run `sbt sbtVersion`, so maybe sbt itself is missing deps? But when I reinstall sbt using these instructions https://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html, it says I already have the latest version installed (1.2.6)

Comment: @MrCholo The dependencies you are missing are `sbt-plugins`. Can you post content of `project/plugins.sbt`?

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc thanks I just updated the OP with that info